# c++ mathematical calculations

Tags: c++, loops, math

I have to solve problem using c++, and can't really come up with solution.

**The condition is.**
In a skyscraper there are a lot of offices, on every office door there must be put plate with its number from 1 to the number of the last office. The plate can only contain one digit, so if office number contains two digits there must be two plates. How many plates total will be needed for all office doors.

The text file is *duom.txt*. with the only value of "16". Means theres 16 offices.

This is what I managed to come up with:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cmath>
# include <iomanip>
# include <fstream>
using namespace std;
const char CDfv [] = ("duom.txt");
const char CRfv [] = ("rez.txt");
int main()
{
  int n;
  int m;
  int o;
  int z;
  ifstream fd (CDfv);
  ofstream fr (CRfv);
  fd>>n;

  for (int i=1;i<10;i++) {
    m=n+1;
    for (int j=1;j>=10;j++) {
      o=n+2;
    }
  }
  z=m+o;
  fr<<z<<" ";
}
fd.close();
fr.close();
return 0;
}
```

I know its not correct, so could someone please help me with this. Also would be very glad if somebody tried compiling it, because my codeblocks refuses to work with compiler even if I installed it seperately manually. :/ but thats another problem.

***-----***

Seems like solution has been found, thanks to everyone who helped me.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cmath>
# include <iomanip>
# include <fstream>
using namespace std;
const char CDfv [] = ("duom.txt");
const char CRfv [] = ("rez.txt");
int main()
{
int limit = 10;
int up = 1;
int viso = 0;
ifstream fd (CDfv);
ofstream fr (CRfv);
fd>>n;
for ( int i = 1; i<=n ;++i ){
    if (i==limit){
        limit*=10;
        up+=1;
    }
    viso += up;
}
        fr<<viso<<" ";

    fd.close();
    fr.close();
    return 0;
}
```

this should work as non text file variant works like charm, here: http://ideone.com/xoFQwn

Comment: You have a `}` before `fd.close()` that will end the scope of `main`, your code will not compile as written. Also it would be great if you formatted your code in a readable fashion.

Comment: z = m+o = (n+1)+(n+2) = 2*n +3;  Is that what you intended?

Comment: n,m,o,z, well, that's perfectly clear.

Comment: You should use `{` and `}` for initializing (char) arrays, not `(` and `)`.

Comment: The code doesn't look like it resolves the requirements.  For example, the number of plates on a floor can be determined mathematically, no loops needed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews could you explain further. Yeah as I thought about it now, loops doesn't seem necessary. What I need is 1=1 if its under under 10. And 1=2 after 10 or more up to 100. Then add up them at the end. But no idea how to make it work.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Maybe it could be done with while loops, but not too sure.

Comment: My point is that with algebra, you don't need loops.  You know you need `n` plates, minimum.  Try this expression: `total = ((n/10)*10 * 2) + (n%10) - 10;`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simply iterate from 1 to the maximum number of offices `n` and add number of required plates to `total`. for 1 to 9 you need 1 plate, for 10 to 99 you need 2 and so on. we implement this by using limit and step. limit indicates when we need more plates. and step indicates how many plate we need for this office.

```
int limit = 10;
int step = 1;
int total = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i<=n ;++i ){
    if (i==limit){
        limit*=10;
        step+=1;
    }
    total += step;
}
cout << total << endl;
```

Comment: Why is the limit multiplying by 10?

Comment: Your variable definitions are missing ';'.

Comment: How does your code resolve the requirements?

Comment: Tried to make it work, changed step with n, cuz its required. Do you think this would work? (Cant compile because my compiler doesnt work :/) http://pastebin.com/G4MFniVt

Comment: test it on www.ideone.com

Comment: i preffer http://cpp.sh/, but it doesnt work with text data files, I guess will have to change code so it wouldnt require text data file, but hey, thanks for a quick answer.

Comment: This code http://ideone.com/xoFQwn, produced result of 280, while it has to be 23 :S

Comment: you should not change step. step and n are completely different things

Comment: http://ideone.com/xoFQwn, oh my god, it worked. Youre a life saver! Thanks so much. Would upvote 100 times if I just could.

Comment: Now just question is, will that shit print out results just aswell in a text file too.

Comment: @Augiz: The answer, as posted, won't compile.  The variable declarations are missing ';'.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah noticed that too, don't worry i'm not THAT stupid to not be able to fix that on my own :). Gonna try your method too.